# Is there a way to determine if a Route 53 recordset is being used or not

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

We have a few route 53 recordsets which are pointing to the same ELB. We are planning to do a cleanup and delete the unused Route 53 recordsets. Is there a way to find out if a Route 53 recordset is actively being used or not?

Is there a access logs or something similar for Route 53 which can be used to determine this?

Comment: I don't believe there is a direct way. Just analyse each entry

Comment: Either your application is expecting requests for each hostname, or it isn't.  You seem to be trying to solve this problem from the wrong direction.  I have at least 7 different telephone numbers in 3 area codes.  Most of them don't receive many calls, but if I told you a specific number to call in the future, the fact that you haven't called can be determined from my call logs, but that doesn't mean it would be okay if that number stopped working.  Also, I get a lot of wrong number calls and some telemarketers, which generate call logs but don't prove that the call was one I wanted.

Comment: how about this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/query-logs.html

Answer (score 3):

Set up a copy of the ELB. Point the record(s) you're looking to delete at the second ELB. Check CloudWatch's request counts for that ELB over the course of a couple days.

Cheaper (but probably a bit more work on your end) would be turning on ELB's logging and processing the resulting logs, which appear to include the hostname. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/access-log-collection.html

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but here is the solution that worked for me. Simply enable logging on the hosted zone (Only works for public hosted zone). Here is the link on how to setup logging (Pretty simple, and works well):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/query-logs.html#query-logs-configuring

Hope this helps.